# using paypal API issue

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use Paypal in my app, but all my attempts failed. I've connected all jars to my App.
For now, i've created an account at https://developer.paypal.com/ , and I'm trying to follow the steps which are described [here](http://www.putler.com/support/faq/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information/), but when I press "profile", it sends me to the "overview" page. So the question is, how can i get account userId, account signature, paypal applicationId and other info? 
ps. i'm using java.
UPD.
here is my code:

```
public boolean verifyAddress(String email) throws PayPalException {
        boolean isValid;
        CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();
        APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();

        profile.setAPIUsername("myUsername");
        profile.setAPIPassword("myPass");
        profile.setSignature("sign");
        profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");

        caller.setAPIProfile(profile);
        AddressVerifyRequestType req = new AddressVerifyRequestType();

        req.setEmail(email);
        req.setStreet("test");
        req.setZip("12345");

        AddressVerifyResponseType resp = (AddressVerifyResponseType) caller
                .call("AddressVerify", req);//throws exception here
        System.out.println(resp.getBuild());
        isValid = resp.getErrors() == null;
        return isValid;
    }
```

and here is one more question: i should set the e-mail,given by payPal(only numbers) or the pass, which i used for sign up?

UPD here is an image i get in sandbox:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to https://developer.paypal.com/. The info you are looking for is in the "API and Payment Card Credentials" tab, in the section "API Credentials". If you haven't yet created a seller test account you must create one first.

In the future you may find useful [PayPal's Integration Wizards](https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php), which generates all the code you need for you.

Edit:

You don't have to use neither your email or your password, only the information provided by PayPal. For example, in the image below the username would be `gemccu_1229982509_biz_api1.cs.com` and the password `QR9WVHAD2PYGC2P9`. Your credentials should be similar to this ones.

[image]

Edit:

As said before, you can find all the info in the "API and Payment Card Credentials" tab at https://developer.paypal.com/. Here you have a screenshot of what I see in mine:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I found it, but my app still doesn't work. it seems that paypal returns nothing or something wrong

Comment: Paste some code of your app so that we can be more helpful. Anyway, if you use the PayPal Integration Wizard I mentioned before you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: I don't have such links! and any info, described on the screenshot I can find find on developer.paypal.com, but not in sandbox...

Comment: I'm afraid that was just a screenshot I found at paypal.com so that you could see the credentials format. I have updated with a screenshot of my sandbox. If yours doesn't look like this one maybe you  haven't created the seller test account correctly.

Comment: so paypal doesn't provide really user-friendly interface, though :(. but i think it would be fair enough to mark your answer as correct, cause you helped and wasted a lot of time, so thank you! :)

Comment: Helgus, you can't find it yet? Let me know and I'll walk you through it.

Comment: Robert, I just gave it up... but if I'll need it, I'll ask you